# поиск по кортежам находящимся в списке. python

Tags: python

всем привет
есть две переменных а и b которой кортежи в списке в данном формате

```
a = 333
b = [(222,),(111,),(333,)]
```

как можно узнать встречается ли значение переменной "а" в "b"

пробовал через count не получается, кроме цикла for это можно как то реализовать? спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж совсем "в лоб" (зато без цикла и сразу понятно, как работает:-)):

```
a = 333
b = [(222,),(111,),(333,)]

a1=(a,)
if a1 in b:
    print ('Встретилось:-)')
```

Comment: Тогда уж `print(((a,) in b and 'Встретилось') or 'Мимо')` ;-))

Comment: @Namerek, не напиши мне тут в прошлый раз вы (или кто-то другой из Великих:-) про возможности `and` и `or` - долго бы я думал, как это вообще работает. А вот зачем я `a1` добавил - сам не понимаю:-)

Answer (score 2):

```py
a = 333
b = [(222,),(111,),(333,)]

print(
    any(map(lambda x: a in x, b))
)
# True
```

Comment: Поясню для участников на моём уровне знаний или идущих к нему:-):
(сам поразбирался в ответе): тут `map` берёт ламбда-функцию и список, как аргументы, и возвращает новый список, где в каждом элементе - результат проверки ламбда-функцией на нахождение `a` в каждом из кортежей в списке. А уж `any` из `[False, False, True]` делает `True`. Полезная ссылка: <https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lambda-anonymous-functions-filter-map-reduce/>

Comment: Но `print((a,) in b)` с тем же результатом всё же попроще будет, хоть и не так познавательно.

Comment: @Сергей, не совсем "с тем же результатом". Данный вариант будет работать даже если в кортежах будет не по одному элементу. К примеру  `[(222, 555),(111, 444),(333, 777)]`. В этом случае мой вариант, так же отработает корректно

Comment: это верно, спасибо, только всегда вопрос - какую решаем задачу, и что является оптимальным. Я решал конкретную учебную, вы - обобщённую. Так, наверное, правильнее, учту на будущее. Но помню, что быстрая сортировка, конечно, лучше "пузырька" для обобщённого случая, да вот на десятке элементов её "пузырёк" обгонит.

Answer (score 1):

вот еще без цикла вариант:

```
a = 333
b = [(222,444),(111,),(333,)]

print(a in sum(b,()))  # True
```